# tomcat 9 vs dependency spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I cannot find a working combination that works on tomcat 9 for a simple dipendecy tree.
because it happens that tomcat9 needs springboot 2.5.x (I choose 2.5.13, that's the one with less conflicts) but there is one I cannot resolve on "jboss-logging".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
  <version>0.2</version>

  <name>xxx</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>xxxxxx</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <tomcat.version>9.0.43</tomcat.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>


        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.13</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.13</version>
  </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.29</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>      
      <version>2.5.13</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>

 <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.13</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin -->

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
 </build>


  <packaging>war</packaging>
  

</project>
```

if I use the last version per springboot 3.0.6 it's working properly on localhost but it doesn't on the webserver (that's tomcat9).
I don't want to install tomcat10 because it isn't supported by the packet manager of debian (11 bullseye).

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not inheriting from `spring-boot-starter-parent` in your POM? It manages dependencies for you that have been tested with the specified Spring Boot version.

Comment: Have a look at the minor version of the tomcat that you are trying to deploy to and match with the minor version that is embedded with selected version of Spring Boot. For example, Spring boot 2.5.13 embeds 9.0.62 and might be best fit to deployed on Tomcat 9.0.62. You can try to match version that fits your need from MVN Repo https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.5.13

Comment: @Cisco i generated a new POM using https://start.spring.io/ but the oldest version supported is 2.7.11, and that's not compatible with tomcat9. if i try to manually change the version a POM exception is raised